# SQL what is wrong with this syntax? BEGIN...IF...RETURN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Below is a excerpt from a function. I keep getting a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'

My code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.convttxt (@mhtztxt VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mhtz FLOAT 

    IF (ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(@mhtztxt)))
        RETURN CONVERT(FLOAT, LTRIM(RTRIM(@mhtztxt))) 

    SET @mhtz = (SELECT 
                     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([COL1], 'xyz', 0)              
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0) 

                 FROM dbo.table1)

    RETURN @mhtz
END
```

Comment: The `IF` statement parenthesis do not match up. From what I can see here.

Comment: `(ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(@mthztt)))` Unbalanced parentheses. 4 opening parentheses and 3 closing. If this is the problem, then I vote to close as simple typographical error.

Comment: Can you show the whole function?

Comment: I only see 3 opening parenthesis

Comment: @bill. On the IF statement there are 4.     IF **(**ISNUMERIC**(**ltrim**(**rtrim**(**@mthztt)))

Comment: Added the rest of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but the replace logic is still missing ;-)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.convttxt (@mhtztxt VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mhtz FLOAT 

    IF ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(@mhtztxt))) = 1 
       SET @mhtz = CONVERT(FLOAT, LTRIM(RTRIM(@mhtztxt))) 
    ELSE
    SELECT @mhtz = 
                     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'xyz', 0)              
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
              ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0) 

                 FROM sys.all_objects
    ;

    RETURN @mhtz
END
```

Comment: SELECT dbo.convttxt (1234)  -> This would work
SELECT dbo.convttxt ('ASDF') -> This would give you an convert-error

Comment: You should consider adding some errorhandling or the try_cast command. Also you sould not use user defined functions in large queries because the query wont be executed in parallel, if this is important to you. CLRs maybe do the job better (:

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed (but @tgr beat me to it).

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.convttxt (@mhtztxt VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @mhtz FLOAT;
  --below: extra parenthesis removed, variable spelled wrong, ISNUMERIC statement was not complete

  IF ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(@mhtztxt)))=1 
  --RETURN convert(FLOAT, ltrim(rtrim(@mhtztxt))) 
    SET @mhtz = convert(FLOAT, ltrim(rtrim(@mhtztxt)));
  ELSE
  SET @mhtz= 
    (SELECT TOP(1)
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([COL1] 
                ,'xyz', 0)              
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0) 
                from (SELECT 1.00 UNION ALL SELECT 2.00) table1(col1)); -- emulating your table

   RETURN @mhtz;
END -- needed an End
```

You can further simplify this like so:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.convttxt (@mhtztxt VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
    CASE 
      WHEN ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(@mhtztxt)))=1 
      THEN convert(FLOAT, ltrim(rtrim(@mhtztxt)))
      ELSE
      (SELECT TOP(1)
          REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([COL1] 
                  ,'xyz', 0),'<Enter Text Here>', 0),'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                  ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0),'<Enter Text Here>', 0),'<Enter Text Here>', 0)
                  ,'<Enter Text Here>', 0),'<Enter Text Here>', 0) 
                  from (SELECT 1.00 UNION ALL SELECT 2.00) table1(col1)) -- emulating your table
    END
END
```